# How do I get USB disk drive inserted and removed events in a service without hearing my hard drive being accessed repeatedly on some O/S's?

Tags: c#, wmi

I use this code in my Windows Service to be notified of USB disk drives being inserted and removed:

```
WqlEventQuery query = new WqlEventQuery("__InstanceOperationEvent", 
    "TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_LogicalDisk' AND TargetInstance.DriveType=2");
query.WithinInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
_deviceWatcher = new ManagementEventWatcher(query);
_deviceWatcher.EventArrived += new EventArrivedEventHandler(OnDeviceEventArrived);
_deviceWatcher.Start();
```

It works on XP and Vista, but on XP I can hear the very noticeable sound of the hard drive being accessed every second. Is there another WMI query that will give me the events without the sound effect?

Comment: The query you have there is not specifically looking for USB devices but rather new disks mounted so would likely trigger when you format a hard disk and not when you insert a USB device that is not disk based such as a mouse.

Comment: Thanks, edited to specify what I really want - USB disk drive insert and remove events. I added the "DriveType=2" (to specify removable disks) hoping it would eliminate hard drive sounds, but no luck.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this applies to your case but we've been using RegisterDeviceNotification in our C# code (which I can't post here) to detect when USB devices are plugged in. There's a handful of native functions you have to import but it generally works well. Easiest to make it work in C++ first and then see what you have to move up into C#.

There's some stuff on koders Code search that appears to be a whole C# device management module that might help:

https://web.archive.org/web/20100329155804/http://www.koders.com/csharp/fidEF5C6B3E2F46BE9AAFC93DB75515DEFC46DB4101.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the link, but it seems to require a window handle for receiving WM_ messages. I'm a service, so I don't have one.

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
using System;
using System.Management;

namespace MonitorDrives
{
class Program
{
    public enum EventType
    {
        Inserted = 2,
        Removed = 3
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ManagementEventWatcher watcher = new ManagementEventWatcher();
        WqlEventQuery query = new WqlEventQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_VolumeChangeEvent WHERE EventType = 2 or EventType = 3");

        watcher.EventArrived += (s, e) =>
        {
            string driveName = e.NewEvent.Properties["DriveName"].Value.ToString();
            EventType eventType = (EventType)(Convert.ToInt16(e.NewEvent.Properties["EventType"].Value));

            string eventName = Enum.GetName(typeof(EventType), eventType);

            Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1} {2}", DateTime.Now, driveName, eventName);
        };

        watcher.Query = query;
        watcher.Start();

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try looking for the InstanceCreationEvent, which will signal the creation of a new Win32_LogicalDisk instance. Right now you're querying for instance operations, not creations.  You should know that the query interval on those events is pretty long - it's possible to pop a USB in and out faster that you'll detect.